# Terminate Fixed Length record with CR ONLY

Tags: filehelpers

The filehelpers engines terminate all fixed length records with CR AND LF. I need to terminate with ONLY CR. Anybody have an idea how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are exporting with something like:

```
engine.WriteFile("Output.Txt", orders);
```

Instead, do this:

```
var output = engine.WriteString(orders);
var fixed = output.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "\n");
File.WriteAllText("Output.Txt", fixed);
```